# Complex layout with RecyclerViews and other views

Tags: android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I see there were a lot of questions about it, but I didn't find any solution so far.

So I need to make a complex layout with several recyclerviews and some other views, for example:
button
recyclewview1
textview
recyclerview2

I need all of this to scroll like a single layout (one after another).
And I also need RecyclerViews to keep their recycling because there will be lots of items.

Is there any standard or third party solution for this? It seems like a pretty common problem, I can't believe google didn't think of anything to solve it.

Comment: You should use one recycler view instead `button + recyclewview1 + textview + recyclerview2`.
Adapter for this RecyclerView should support several view types. i.e. for position 0 return button, for  <1, n> position some view that you wanted to use in recyclewview1, then for n+1 position TextView and for <n+2, n+2 +m) some view that you wanted to use in recyclerview2.

Comment: @kibao, yes, I am aware of that solution but it's too complicated since I have gridlayoutmanager. Thanks anyway